Solving a Markov chain matrix stationary distribution for a vector of probabilities
I am having trouble with the following question. I am not sure I have the right answer.
A Markov chain with state space S = {1, 2} has transition matrix
$$ P = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1-\sigma & \sigma 
\end{bmatrix} $$
where 0< $\sigma$ < 1.
Find the stationary distribution for this process as a probability vector with elements depending on $\sigma$.
Using this general formula: $\pi^T= \pi^T P$
$$
(\pi_1 \space \space \pi_2) \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1-\sigma & \sigma 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Solving the system of equations:
$$
\pi_1 + \pi_2 = 1 \\
\pi_2(1-\sigma) = \pi_1 \\
\pi_1 + \pi_2\sigma = \pi_2
$$
Like so:
$$
\pi_1 = 1 - \pi_2 \\ 
$$
Substitute this into the third equation:
$$
\Rightarrow \pi_2(1-\sigma) = 1-\pi_2 \\
2\pi_2 - \pi_2\sigma = 1 \\
2-\sigma = \frac{1}{\pi_2} \\
\sigma = 2 - \frac{1}{\pi_2}
$$
Here I get stuck. When I substitute sigma back into the matrix everything comes out to $\pi_1 + \pi_2 = 1$, which to me is a good sign. It means I have the right value for $\sigma\$.
How do I go from here to identifying a probability vector in $\sigma$ for the stationary distribution?
Thank you in advance.

It's unclear how you got your system of equations? What general formula are you using for the stationary distribution?

The first of the two equations $\pi P=\pi$ yields
$$
\pi_2(1-\sigma)=\pi_1.
$$
Since $\pi_1+\pi_2=1$, we get
$$
\pi_1=\frac{1-\sigma}{2-\sigma},\quad \pi_2=\frac{1}{2-\sigma}.
$$
